# Make your name stand out like using /me command but instead of being bold, the my name should be like a link?

Tags: skype

I'm wondering about a trick (used in Skype chatting) to do something very similar to what you can do with the command `/me`, such as if my Skype name is `abc`, after typing `/me is feeling tired`, the actual message sent will be `abc is feeling tired`. The message is aligned at center and **`abc`** is in bold.

I saw a guy send a message much like that but his user name was not bolded but appeared as a link. Hovering the link I can see a tooltip showing something like `skype:his_user_name?chat`.

I would like to do something like that but really Googling around did not help much. I'm not sure if it involves but he chat as the conversation creator (in group chat).

Thank you very much!

Comment: Sounds like this is a feature of skype doing this automatically when you have entered data in your profile, or something similar. Or perhaps linked to a microsoft account.

Comment: @LPChip could you try that yourself first to see if it works? In fact I don't quite understand what you mentioned.

Comment: I don't use skype, so I can't test it. But I know how Microsoft works. Usually when it does something like making a link clickable, and linking to a profile, its due to it being linked as such. So it is likely that this works because they use skype with a microsoft profile. If I were able to test it, the above would not have been a comment, but an answer. I've posted the comment so others can test it and post an answer, or at least you can try it.